# Is there a way to track PDF openings within an e-mail with Google Analytics?

Tags: email, pdf, google-analytics

I am working with a marketing team and they want to track the openings and time spent of attached PDFs sent with their e-mail campaigns. In my research, I've found ways to track a PDF that is hosted on the site (setting goals and event triggers) but not within an actual campaign e-mail. Would this be possible? The company is using MailChimp if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a definitive **no** answer for this, if we think about how this would work though I believe the answer is *no*.

If the PDF is an attachment to the email, once the email reaches the recipient there is no way for MailChimp to be notified that the attachment was interacted with unless the email client knew to notify MailChimp.

If it is a requirement to send the PDF via attachment in the email, then you might want to look at embedding JavsScript within the PDF to call a web service (or something to poke Google Analytics) when it is opened. This has a few downsides to it though, not all PDF viewing applications support JavaScript, for security Acrobat puts up a dialog letting users know that JavaScript is attempting to execute and they may refuse permission, and that for it to work in the free Adobe Reader the PDFs need to be reader extended (or reader enabled).